# Unexpected behavior with mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on the menu, the menu shows up, but when the pointer is moved away from the menu, it hides after 2-5 seconds.

I want the menu to toggle when clicked, and explicitly hide when I click anywhere else on the page, as seen on [this demo.](http://demos.9lessons.info/DropMenu/MyDemo.html)
[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehf16td6/)
My code is as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".MyAccount").click(function() {
    var X = $(this).attr('id');
    if (X == 1) {
      $(".submenu").hide();
      $(this).attr('id', '0');
    } else {
      $(".submenu").show();
      $(this).attr('id', '1');
    }
  });
  //Mouseup textarea false
  $(".submenu").mouseup(function() {
    return false
  });
  $(".myaccount").mouseup(function() {
    return false
  });
  //Textarea without editing.
  $(document).mouseup(function() {
    $(".submenu").hide();
    $(".MyAccount").attr('id', '');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="MyAllMenu" style='margin: 50px'>
  <div class="MyMenu">
    <a class="MyAccount">
      <span>My Settings</span>
    </a>
    <div class="submenu" style="display: none;">
      <ul class="AllMenuList">
        <li>
          <a href="/Default.aspx">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#Profile">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#settings">Settings</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#feedback">Send Feedback</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#signout">Sign Out</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you give us as a fiddle?

Comment: Doesn't that demo do exactly what you want it to do?

Comment: fiddle added and is not working fine take the mouse away

Comment: I've tried your fiddle and it works: I click, it shows the menu. I click elsewhere: it hides the menu. I re-click: it reshows, I click it again, it rehides.
If I just move the mouse without clicking, it doesn't hide. I don't see the problem?

Comment: you have to keep the mouse pointer inside the result window. by the way i tried it using ie no problem found. it seems the problem just in chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i have a dictionary application that reads any text from the page on hover, and when disabling this feature, every thing works as it should be.

I didn't notice that because I tried on two computers and it happened that i was using this app on both of them.

Answer (score 1):

check on [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/n5ms7y1z/1/)  . onclick hide/show menu working now . i have  added not(".myaccount",".submenu")  to mouse up event of document.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".MyAccount").click(function () {

        var X = $(this).attr('id');
        if (X == '1') {
            $(".submenu").hide();
            $(this).attr('id', '0');
        }
        else {
            $(".submenu").show();
            $(this).attr('id', '1');
        }
    });

    //Textarea without editing.
    $(document).not(".myaccount",".submenu").mouseup(function () {
        $(".submenu").hide();
        $(".MyAccount").attr('id', '');
    });
 });
```

Comment: it seems the problem in chrome only

Comment: @OptPrutal  i am using chrome on MAC and it works fine . onclick hide/show menu

Comment: it seems a browser problem

Comment: It's not (only) browser. OP is using jquery 1.6.4 according to his fiddle, but this answer is using 2.1.0.

Comment: this one works but when i click away the menu doesn't hide can you just edit the main fiddle and show the link

Comment: @OptPrutal what is wrong with main fiddle ?? it works same as demo link ? what issue you have?

Comment: if i use chrome, when i click the menu, the menu shows up and when i move the mouse away from the menu it hides. well it should  not hide till i click the menu or any where else. if you are testing on fiddler keep the mouse pointer in the result frame to see what i mean. again this is happening only when using chrome

Comment: @OptPrutal which version of chrome you use?

Comment: i have change version of jquery in this fiddle and i cant see problem you mention .. it work fine no menu hide untill click out side or main link http://jsfiddle.net/ehf16td6/3/

Comment: chrome Version 41.0.2272.101 m

Comment: @OptPrutal i use same version on windows 7 check my updated fiddle in last message .. i update jquery version .. it seem work for me same as demo

Comment: same problem. i will upload a video tomorrow showing the problem i know its weird , i have tried it on two computers so far (w7 and w8) same issue